# Remove Recent List in VLC Players on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

VLC player is one of the item most used on my Windows 7 machine. When I click "Start", I\it appears as "pinned" at the program list.

When I mouse over to the VLC players, I will see a list of recently played videos. Now, is there anyway I can remove the recent list? I tried to remove the recent list from the VLC player application, but this doesn't remove the recent list as remembered by the Windows OS system.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Windows 7:

1. Go to the Taskbar and Start Menu properties
2. Go to "Jump List", uncheck "Store and display recently opened items"
3. Click Apply then OK

Comment: I add this because people using win10 might land here too: In Win10 this option was moved: Desktop > right click > Personalize > Start > Show recently used files jumplist > disable.

Comment: This isn't an actual answer to what's been asked, which was not to disable Windows' jump list functionality, but to remove the recent list of played videos in VLC from being displayed in a jump list.  These are not the same things and should not be treated as such.  

The only solution to what was asked would be clearing the contents of the  appropriate `*.automaticDestinations-ms` file and prevent it from being written to.

Comment: as of today, turning off the settings in VLC to store recently played items (`settings -> all settings -> interface -> main interfaces -> qt -> save the recently played items in the menu`) will prevent any new items being added to the jump list, and then you can clear the ` *.automaticDestinations-ms` file to get rid of old entries

Answer (score 6):

From [How to Hide Recently Played Files on VLC Player](http://www.recipester.org/Recipe:Hide_Recently_Played_Files_on_VLC_Player_32902972)

> Click the Media button on the main
>   menu, select Recent Media-> Clear.
>   Then you have deleted the recent media
>   list.

[image]

As regarding Windows 7, see this article:
[How to Disable/Clear Recent MRU Items from Jump List of Windows 7](http://www.blogsdna.com/2324/how-to-disableclear-recent-mru-items-from-jump-list-of-windows-7.htm)

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: Where do you see a recent list in Windows?

Comment: @harrymc, there are two places where I can see it. 1. When I click "Start", the vlc player is pinned there. 2. When I launch vlc, and I minimize it, zoom my mouse over it, a "recent list" will also appear. Note that after I Clear everything in Recent Media ( as you show), the recent list in Windows is still there.

Comment: I believe you are referring to the MRU list. This may help: http://www.blogsdna.com/2324/how-to-disableclear-recent-mru-items-from-jump-list-of-windows-7.htm

Answer (score 3):

On my machine, deleting this file clears the VLC jump list:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\abbca1611c617117.automaticDestinations-ms
```

I'm not sure how the `abbca1611c617117` basename is derived, or if it will be constant across different environments.

I found it by searching for files containing known jump list entry filenames in the `AutomaticDestinations` folder (for example, play `example.mp4` in VLC, then search for `example.mp4` in files in `AutomaticDestinations`).

Comment: More about it, including some insights about basenames (AppIds) -> https://www.blackbagtech.com/blog/2017/01/12/windows-10-jump-list-forensics/

Comment: aaand even more here http://cyberforensicator.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/1-s2.0-S1742287616300202-main.2-14.pdf

Comment: Earlier I had found the MSDN docs on AppIDs but it just said the OS generates one when the app (like VLC) doesn't explicitly specify one. The CyberForensicator link you posted is much more helpful: it reveals that implicit AppIDs are the CRC-64 checksum of the executable's path. This led me to [JumpLists file names and AppID calculator](http://www.hexacorn.com/blog/2013/04/30/jumplists-file-names-and-appid-calculator/), which includes a detailed description of the algorithm and an implementation in Perl (`appid_calc.pl`). It wasn't able to regenerate my VLC AppID but it might work for others.

Comment: I was able to tweak `appid_calc.pl` and now it can correctly regenerate my VLC AppID. I needed to disable the environment path substitution that was converting `C:` into `%SYSTEMDRIVE%` and then I got the expected output. The value of the `SystemDrive` environment variable is indeed `C:` on my Windows 7 x64 computer, but I guess that particular expansion isn't using when hashing executable paths or something.

`c:\programs\Multimedia\VLC\vlc.exe` → `ABBCA1611C617117`

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*(Simply disabling jump lists in Windows isn't an acceptable solution, nor an actual answer to what's been asked)*</sup>

**To disable VLC, or any specific app's, jumplists:**

1. Navigate to path below → Change view to: *detailed* → Sort by: *date (ascending)*:

   ```cmd
   %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
   ```
2. Play file in VLC → Close VLC → Note `.automaticDestinations-ms` file modified in #1, or:

   ```cmd
   # Last modified will be the last in the list:
     Cmd /c Dir /O:D /T:W "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations"
   ```
3. **CLI:**

   ```cmd
   # Clear file contents (should be 0KB after):
     Cmd /c Type > "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\<name>.automaticDestinations-ms"

   # Change file attributes to Read-Only:
     Attrib +R "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\<name>.automaticDestinations-ms"
   ```

   **GUI:**

   1. Right-click `.automaticDestinations-ms` file from #2 → *Open with Notepad*
   2. Select all content: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> → Delete content: <kbd>Del</kbd> → Save: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
   3. Right-click `.automaticDestinations-ms` file → *Properties* → Tick: *Read-only* → *OK*
4. Play file in VLC to verify correct `.automaticDestinations-ms` file was modified → See #1, or:

   ```cmd
   # The .automaticDestinations-ms file should remain 0KB in size:
     Dir "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\<name>.automaticDestinations-ms"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10:

1. Right click on desktop, Personalize
2. Go to Start item
3. Turn off "Show recently opened items in Jump Lists on Start or the taskbar"

Comment: Any reason to add this answer ( instead of editing the accepted one)? FYI, the same information was added as [a comment](http://superuser.com/questions/185307/remove-recent-list-in-vlc-players-on-windows-7/1111404#comment1476761_452104) to the accepted answer.

Comment: I don't see why we would edit the original answer, they are both different for the 2 Windows versions. For the comment, I saw it was there but this should be an answer. I thought it was more productive to put an answer than commenting under him saying this should be an answer.

Comment: This isn't an actual answer to what's been asked, which was not to disable Windows' jump list functionality, but to remove the recent list of played videos in VLC from being displayed in a jump list.  These are not the same things and should not be treated as such.  

The only solution to what was asked would be clearing the contents of the  appropriate `*.automaticDestinations-ms` file and prevent it from being written to.